# How can determine if a angle is betwen two angles?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have the following information about the problem

- Start point
- Size (angle between 0 and 360)
- End point (start point + size)
- Tarjet angle.

The questions is how can determine if a tarjet angle is between start and end point

**Example**

\begin{bmatrix}
case&start&end&size\\
a&350&6&16\\
b&0&90&90\\
c&350&100&55\\
d&0&0&0\\
e&0&0&360\\
\end{bmatrix}

**Case A**

- 270 outside
- 351 inside

**Case B**

- 360 outside
- 45 inside

**Case C**

- 102 outside
- 1 inside

**Case D**

- All are outside

**Case D**

- All are inside

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the difference: "tarjet" angle $-$ start angle. If negative, repeatedly add 360° until the result is positive. Check if result is less than size: if so, it's inside.